# Windows 7 x64: Nothing happens when I click "Rate this computer"

Tags: windows-7, windows

Strange problem, I must have installed Windows 7 now at least 40 times, never had this issue.

When I try click rate the computer , nothing happens.

I have activated Windows, and yes it is a genuine and valid product key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer:

More of a workaround, but its enough:

Go into an elevated command prompt (cmd.exe run as administrator) and type in:

winsat formal